# can anyone explain the below express.js code to me please?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express

As the title says, I don't understand the following express.js code that I saw in a tutorial I am following. The tutorial is for building a Node.js, Express and PostgreSQL REST API.

This code is near the bottom of the index.js file, and I think I understand that it is setting up the routes, but I don't know how it works and can't find anything online. Also, if my index.js file has, for example, 2 GET endpoints, how would I adapt the below code to do both of the GET routes?

```
app
.route('/books')
// GET endpoint
.get(getBooks)
// POST endpoint
.post(addBook)
```

Comment: When someone sends GET request getBooks is triggered and on POST addBook is triggred

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, this code just says that request on `/books` might have GET and POST methods, hence, will be resolved using different functions.

More detailed, Node JS allows creating a chain of calls and in that particular example when HTTP request on `/books` endpoint happens, the framework will go through this chain and if the request method matches with implementation (*e.g. GET request sent*) then the related function will be called.

If you are wondering why `getBooks` and `addBook` w/o any context or anything, that is just yet another way of passing arguments in Node JS. In particular either of these functions look like:

```
export const getBooks = (req, res) => {//some magic here}
```

But be careful using it like this, cos you might get some weird behavior when you need to pass `this` context for example.

In fact, if you add two `.get` calls, then depends on the function implementation either only the first will be executed (*if the function returns the response*) or both one after another will be called.

Comment: Great, thanks very much for the explanation. So from my understand and from what you have said this is just another way of writing - app.get('/calendarEvent', (req, res) => { ... });